# Can the Graph API be a substitute for the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

This is more of an 'Is this possible' question. A developer on the team suggested using Azure AD for user management, but one of the requirements is that the app admin be able to add/manage user access through the application without having to go to the Azure Portal.

So the question is, is the Graph API (or some other mechanism) full featured enough to replace the portal (at least for basic user set up and management) and allow all actions to be done from the application UI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to your question is Yes. Graph API can be used to manage users and their access to applications instead of using Azure Portal. In fact, Azure Portal itself makes use of Graph API to perform these operations.

You may also need to use [`Azure REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) if you're planning on managing Azure resources as well through this custom application especially [`Authorization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/) APIs if you want to manage access to Azure resources (Azure Role-based access control) through your application.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Would you happen to know of a good example that shows the basics of adding/managing users?

Comment: Microsoft Graph REST API reference is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0. You can use Graph Explorer to learn about how to perform basic operations: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer. However I would recommend using SDKs instead of using REST API directly. If you're using .Net, you can take a look at MS Graph SDK for .Net - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet. HTH.